# Qt Extending my own widget

Tags: c++, qt, widget, extends, extending

To put it simply, I want a new class that extends a custom widget that I've made, and thus have full access to it's UI.

I've tried several different methods so far based on how one would normally subclass/extend classes, but I'm somehow failing horribly for so many different reasons.

Additionally, simply using my widget as a member in my new class wouldn't do for this situation.

Can someone illustrate a quick example of how I would do this? I have done a bunch of searching but I can't seem to find any hits relating to exactly what I'm trying to do
If all else fails I will simply copy over the code and make an actual new widget, which technically would have saved me lots time, but it just doesn't feel right doing that.

My first instinct was to do something like this ( `Qwe` being my new class, `Asd` being the widget ):

```
class Qwe : Asd {public: ...}
```

And I even made the widget's Ui public, but then I just got the error :

> use of undefine type Ui::Asd

whenever I tried to access the Ui's elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have a custom widget named `BaseWidget` and a child widget named `ChildWidget`. Declare `BaseWidget` as usually, but make its `ui` member protected instead of private, like this:

```
protected:
  Ui::BaseWidget *ui;
```

Declare `ChildWidget` as an ordinary widget derived from `BaseWidget`. Make sure you include `ui_BaseWidget.h` in the `ChildWidget.cpp` file, just as you do it in `BaseWidget.cpp` (this include and the header itself is generated by Qt).

Header:

```
#include "BaseWidget.h"

class ChildWidget : public BaseWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit ChildWidget(QString text, QWidget *parent = 0);    
};
```

Source:

```
#include "ChildWidget.h"
#include "ui_BaseWidget.h"

ChildWidget::ChildWidget(QString text, QWidget *parent) :
  BaseWidget(parent)
{
  ui->label->setText(text);
}
```